# WPF: 'Cannot change cell selection when the SelectionUnit is FullRow' when navigating to other page

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I have a simple `DataGrid`

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
          ItemsSource="{Binding Items, Mode=TwoWay}"               
          CanUserAddRows="True" CanUserDeleteRows="True" 

          SelectionMode="Single" 
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem, Mode=TwoWay}" SelectionUnit="FullRow" >
      <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" 
                          Binding="{Binding Path=Name, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                          CellStyle="{StaticResource CellDefaultStyle}" />
</DataGrid>
```

I use it on a `Page` in a `NavigationWindow`. When I open the page and navigate to another page then all is fine.

But when I open the page and select a row in the DataGrid and then navigate to another page then I get the error:

> Cannot change cell selection when the SelectionUnit is FullRow.

But I want to keep the `FullRow` selection unit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was the CellStyle I downloaded somewhere to prettify my rows. After removing the property

```
CellStyle="{StaticResource CellDefaultStyle}"
```

it worked normally.